# de Laval nozzle geometry

Tags: fluid-dynamics, geometry, rocket-science

After doing some research I was not able to find any information on the geometry of the de Laval nozzle. Are there some kind of ratios that the different sections' radii and lengths have to be in? Angles would be helpful, too.

If someone knows of some kind of blueprint like this:

[image: de Laval nozzle with dimensions]

that would be really nice. The dimensions missing above are just examples, the blueprint does not have to include these exactly, similar ones are okay, too.

And do the same ratios and angles work on different scales as well? Or are there different ones depending on the actual size of the nozzle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is taken from [Aerorocket](http://www.aerorocket.com/Nozzle/Nozzle.html), which is a DeLaval nozzle analysis program and [Wikipedia Delaval Nozzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Laval_nozzle)

Rather than answer by trying to find tables showing the results of different ratios, angles and scaling effects, if instead you use the Aerorocket program, it seems to provide a large range of options to try out the performance of the nozzle,  by adjusting the parameters you have listed in your question.

The performance of the Delaval nozzle is dependent on the fact that  hot exhaust gases have different properties depending on their speed regime, that is subsonic or supersonic. The velocity  of a subsonic flow of gas increases where the nozzle constriction occurs, as the mass flow rate  remains constant throughout. The gas flow involved on  a de Laval type  nozzle has the property that gas entropy is almost  constant. In a subsonic regime, compessability effects occur and sound waves propagate. At the constriction/ throat, the gas reaches Mach 1.0.

[image]

Diagram of a de Laval nozzle, showing approximate flow velocity (v), together with the effect on temperature (T) and pressure (P).

Image Source: [Wikipedia Delaval Nozzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Laval_nozzle)

Downstream of the nozzle, expansion of the gas occurs in the bell of the nozzle.  As the gas enters the nozzle, it is moving at subsonic velocities. As the throat contracts, the gas is forced to accelerate until at the nozzle throat, where the cross-sectional area is the smallest, the axial velocity becomes sonic. From the throat the cross-sectional area then increases, the gas expands and the axial velocity becomes progressively more supersonic.

The linear velocity of the exiting exhaust gases can be calculated using the following equation:

$${ v_{e}={\sqrt {{\frac {TR}{M}}\cdot {\frac {2\gamma }{\gamma -1}}\cdot \left[1-\left({\frac {p_{e}}{p}}\right)^{\frac {\gamma -1}{\gamma }}\right]}}}$$

where:

$v_{e}$= exhaust velocity at nozzle exit

$T$= absolute temperature of inlet gas,

$R$= universal gas law constant,

$M$= the gas molecular mass (also known as the molecular weight)

$ \gamma = { {\frac {c_{p}}{c_{v}}}}$ = isentropic expansion factor

$ c_{p}$ and $c_{v}$ are specific heats of the gas at constant pressure and constant volume respectively

$ p_{e}$ = absolute pressure of exhaust gas at nozzle exit,

$p$ = absolute pressure of inlet gas.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is no one, single, general purpose de Laval nozzle geometry - there are infinite configurations. In fact, you could sketch out your best, educated guess at a nozzle and it would be absolutely perfect… but only for some particular operating parameters. You have to make it yours - a design applicable to your needs, limitations, and resources.

All the nozzle shapes are based on the standard rocket equations you will find, with all their multiple variables. To design a nozzle, you need to start by picking variables specific to your design conditions. In fact, this is why (space) rockets are usually multi-staged - the first stage is a  rocket nozzle ideal for a propellant at sea level, but the next stage would be the most efficient nozzle designed for the next operating conditions (new altitude, new weight, etc.) with efficiency trade offs all the way to space. You can see the effect of this in a tight rocket jet stream with shock rings (under-expansion) at launch (atm. P), which evolves into a fat plume flame (over-expansion) by the time the next stage needs to be ignited at a higher altitude (lower atm. P).

Generally, at the amateur level, you start by identifying your sustainable, achievable initial pressure in the nozzle chamber (input/combustion chamber P), and your final pressure (output/exhaust P). For max eff., your output/exhaust P should match your exhaust environment - most likely the local atmospheric pressure. So define your pressures and plug into (Pe/P0) equations (Pe - output/exhaust/local environment P; P0 - input/source/chamber P), which gives up your max achievable Mach (M) from that pressure difference, etc., to plug into other equations.

Then you might define your maximum throat area (A*) which is essentially your max possible throat diameter (d*), which is likely based on the sustainable flow rate your source can achieve and limitations of materials/expenses, etc.. Thus, an 8 foot throat diameter is likely out of your realm of possibilities, whereas a 0.25 inch throat diameter may be doable. Graphing out (A/A*) (A - nozzle area at some Mach number M; A* - nozzle area at the throat [M=1]) to Mach (M) essentially gives the diameters/radii (profile) of the nozzle you need to make, albeit scaled [ r/r* = d/d*/2 = sqrt(A/A*)/2 ]. It’s fairly easy to make a calculator program, or more detailed Numbers/Excel spreadsheet, to instantly solve and even directly graph out nozzle designs based on your input values. The graphed shapes are of ratios to the throat (as are all the common rocket equations), so scale the shape up until it matches your actual/physical throat diameter. That’s YOUR de Laval nozzle!

But mind you, this is all “ideal”. In reality, the final nozzle is what comes out of a long refinement feedback loop. For instance, you may find that your actual measured source P while operating isn’t what you thought it would be; or your materials can’t handle the thrust while under the high-heat flow; or all is great but you need more thrust for a bigger load; or a million other non-ideal conditions pop up, and you must often reconfigure your shape/optimize your design. It is rocket science after all. And just when you think you’ve finally got it all figured out, an o-ring operating at some cryogenic temp you didn’t realize was occurring finally fails seconds into launch, and you’ve got to go back and reconfigure something again. [ Insert hundreds of hours of rocket failure videos here, of every rocket prototype from Goddard, to NASA, to SpaceX - you might not think of everything, but reality surely does! ]